# Launching a login view before the tab bar controller is displayed

Tags: ios5, tabs, controller, storyboard

I have an ios5 app developed using storyboards that currently displays a tab bar controller view on initial launch. I would like to display a login screen before the tab bar controller is displayed. The user would enter his username & password, the system would then authenticate the user and then if successful, display the tab bar controller.

I have tried the following 3 options with no luck.. any ideas ?

```
(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

    // Option 1
    UITabBarController *tabBarController = (UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController;
    PointsViewController *firstVC = [[tabBarController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0];
    UIViewController *loginViewController = [[LoginViewController alloc] init];
    [firstVC.navigationController pushViewController:loginViewController animated:YES];

    // Option 2
    UITabBarController *tabBarController = (UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController;
    UIViewController *loginViewController = [[LoginViewController alloc] init];
    [tabBarController presentViewController:loginViewController animated:NO completion:nil];  

    // Option 3
    UITabBarController *tabBarController = (UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController;
    UIViewController *loginViewController = [[LoginViewController alloc] init];
    [tabBarController presentModalViewController:loginViewController animated:NO];

    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Finally figured this one out.. here is what you need to do:

1. Add a standalone login view to the storyboard.
2. Select the login view and in the attributes inspector, check the 'Is Initial View Controller'. This will switch the initial view being launched from the tab controller to the login view, thereby solving the whole issue of displaying the login screen first.
3. Add a button to the login view and create a segue to load the tab controller on push of the button. (Or you can create a segue from the login view to the tab controller view and programmatically invoke the segue as necessary).
4. Select the login view and choose option Editor > Embed In > Navigation Controller
5. In the attributes inspector for the Navigation controller, uncheck the 'Shows Navigation Bar' option (this is a cosmetic change; I am assuming you don't need a navigation bar showing on the login screen !!)

That's it :)

Comment: how do I pass value to the firstviewcontroller of the  tab bar using segue ? I couldnt get it to work

Comment: you don't pass a value with the segue. One possible option is to store the value you want to pass as a property on your AppDelegate and simply access the value from the target view.

Comment: It works! But how to disable push to new window if password is incorrect?

Comment: Solved:Do not link the segue from a UI element such as a button. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20715257/login-page-goes-to-main-uitabbar-view-even-with-incorrect-login-info   Then: [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"PushRedViewController" sender:sender];

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the following links

[stackoverflow.com/questions/16351348/…](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16351348/%E2%80%A6)

[link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8221787/%E2%80%A6)

[link 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8221787/%E2%80%A6)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a modal view.  You can check if the user is logged in.  If not then you can use a modal view to get the login information.  You can create a UIViewController in the storyboard and then use the instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: method to create the login screen from the storyboard.  Then simply show it modally.

Comment: And where would you launch the modal window from? The viewDidAppear method of the first tab? Is there a way to launch the modal window before the tabs are loaded?

Comment: If you want it to display before things are rendered, then you would use the viewWillAppear to do the check and launch the modal view.  Once you modally open a new view controller/view the processing waits until the modal view is closed.  The method would be in the root view controller of the tab controller and not the tab controller.  If needed this can be placed into each of the root view controllers of you tab control or you can subclass UIViewControl and use it for each.

Comment: I tried this. What I see happening is that the initial tab gets loaded and then the modal window is overlaid on top of it. Visually this is not pleasing. I would like the user to see the login window first. I have the launch of the login view being performed from the viewWillAppear method on the first tab. Here is what my code looks like.
<pre><code>
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    // Display the login view modally
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"ShowLogin" sender:self];

}</code></pre>

Comment: Ok.  I have done this with iOS4 with success but I haven't tried this with iOS5 and storyboards so it's possible the timing may be a little different.  Here's one more thought.  Instead of using storyboard's segue try presenting modally manually (as in iOS 4) and set the "animated" to NO.  If the display order is still wrong then I would consider create a view with the user ID and login programmatically.  Then in the viewDidLoad I would add it as a subview the current view.  It's a little more more but should be able to control the view order.  Hold a reference to remove it later.

Answer (score 0):

I met this problem just now and I have perfectly solved this by adding the following code, which you also didn't use.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    ...
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
}
```