# How to handle the push notifications for a tabbar, where my tabbar controller is far away from the root view controller

Tags: ios, ios7, storyboard, apple-push-notifications

I have successfully implemented the `push notification part` in my application. But I am facing the issues in `handling the push notification flow`.

**My requirement is**: after tapping on push notification, I want to navigate to the tabbar where my tabbar is far away from the root view. Please look the below flow. Sorry I dont have enough reputations to post my storyboard image.

```
root view controller                           | ---> controller 4 --> TABBAR CONTROLLER 
   ---> login view controller                  | ---> controller 2
               ---> *side menu view controller | ---> controller 1
                    *(like Facebook side menu)
                                               | ---> controller 3
```

Comment: Look at my answer here , Almost similar **http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16351348/example-for-login-screen-modally-based-on-storyboard/16351631#16351631**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Identifying and Push to the ViewController ([Look at my another Anser Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16351348/example-for-login-screen-modally-based-on-storyboard/16351631#16351631))

Implement this method at **AppDelegate**

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
{
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
            UITabBarController *obj=[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"tab"];
            self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden=YES;
            [self.navigationController pushViewController:obj animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Almost the problem is solved. Suppose if my top view controller is tabbar with one of the tabs. Then at that time if I get a push notification, it is navigating to the other tabbar instance again. So when I come back, will cross two tabbar instances. Any idea?