# UIViewController and UITabBarControllers with Storyboard

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, uistoryboard

Suppose I have an app that STARTS with a UIViewController.  But IF the user presses a button on that UIViewController, I want the app to switch over to a UITabBarController interface.

I'm working in storyboards, and I can't seen to create this kind of setup?

Comment: why you can't see to create this kind of setup?

Comment: This can't be done as explained well in below, alternatively You can try by initialising  with UINavigationController, Check my Answer Here **http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16351348/example-for-login-screen-modally-based-on-storyboard/16351631#16351631**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Though you can add a tabBarController as a child of another viewController,it's not recomended 
practice of using tabbarController,You must use UITabBarController as rootViewController i.e. root of your window.

> The Views of a Tab Bar Controller Because the UITabBarController class
>   inherits from the UIViewController class, tab bar controllers have
>   their own view that is accessible through the view property. When
>   deploying a tab bar interface, you must install this view as the root
>   of your window. Unlike other view controllers, a tab bar interface
>   should never be installed as a child of another view controller.

Have a look at: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITabBarController_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: obviously...viewController with root arrow on storyboard is only parent other are child of the same. it is hierarchical like tree in datastructure..