# IOS login required for certain tabs with storyboard

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, authentication, storyboard

My question is based on the following question, but my case is reversed.

[Example for login screen modally based on storyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16351348/example-for-login-screen-modally-based-on-storyboard)

I would like to have a few tabs private for users only so required login, my storyboard is below:
[image]

Below is my code in custom tabBarController

```
@interface PNTabBarController ()

@end

@implementation PNTabBarController

- (void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item
{
    NSUInteger indexOfTab = [tabBar.items indexOfObject:item];
    NSLog(@"%lu", (unsigned long)indexOfTab);
    if (indexOfTab == 2 || indexOfTab == 3) {
        PFUser *currentUser = [PFUser currentUser];
        NSLog(@"%@", currentUser.username);
        if(currentUser == nil){          
            PNLoginViewController *obj = [[PNLoginViewController alloc]init];
            [self presentViewController:obj animated:YES completion:NULL];
        }
        else{
            NSLog(@"%@", currentUser.username);
        }
    }
}
```

But what happens is a dark screen when I click the 2 or 3 tab. What should be the correct way to achieve this?

Comment: `if(currentUser == nil){ NSLog(@"%@", currentUser.username);` ... logic problem?

Comment: Yes you are right, thanks for reminding my careless mistake.

Comment: tried `initWithNibName` for `PNLoginViewController`?

Comment: Clarification needed: is `PNLoginViewController` not appearing & dark screen shown instead?

Comment: @ShivanRaptor Yes the PNLoginViewController is not appearing only dark screen shown

Comment: As you use Storyboard, you should use `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:` instead.

Comment: @Akhilrajtr what is the difference between initWithNibName and init, and what should I pass in the NSString?

Comment: extra information: for non-Storyboard user / would like to call a XIB separately, use `initWithNibName:` call. The parameter is the XIB file name without the extension; rarely use these days after storyboard becomes mainstream.