# i am using parse for signup/login functionality in my iOS app,i have a small issue in it.please help me

Tags: ios

if the user is registering first time in my app he has to signup otherwise he has to do just login.what is the condition we use to check whether user is new or existing user.

I'm following [this link](https://parse.com/docs/ios_guide#users/iOS)

Comment: You need to do by yourself accordingly... Something similar to this **http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16351348/example-for-login-screen-modally-based-on-storyboard/16351631#16351631**

Comment: thanks kumar.can we compare the user details that were entered with the details existing in parse database?

Comment: @chaithanya that link isn't relevant to your question. It can all be handled in one view controller. No need for all that extra stuff. It also has no references to parse and how to know if a user is logged in currently

Comment: in my app in home page i have two text fields user name and password.two buttons forgot and done.if i click on done it has to check whether user is existing or new user.if the user is new we have to move to signup view controller and if the user is existing we have to move to some other view controller.how to achieve it @soulshined

Comment: @chaithanya i would suggest doing it the way parse has set up, it creates less storyboard clutter and simplifies the process. The link is in my answer. They also take care of the rest (checking to see if that user is valid, checking to see if the password and username keys match etc)

Comment: thanks soul shined i will check it

Comment: @chaithanya if your using parse 1.6 the colors and backgrounds images in the tutorial are outdated. They look cleaner and fresher now. See [here](http://blog.parse.com/2014/11/06/introducing-the-new-parseui-for-ios/) but the coding is all the same.

Answer (score 0):

Parse has a complete run down of how to implement this into your project. Assuming your coding for objective c look at their documentation and their own tutorial for signing up or signing in users

https://parse.com/tutorials/login-and-signup-views

They take care of all the heavy lifting, producing UIAlertViews if the password is not correct, displaying one if they don't fill out all the required fields, ensures the username and password keys match etc etc etc)