# performSegueWithIdentifier don't show new view

Tags: ios, xcode, ios5, storyboard, segue

I make test app that show second view when the init view is shown. My code is this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showSecondView" sender:self];
}
```

But second view is not shown. Can someone help me. Thanks a lot

Comment: Well first question is, did you create the segue with exactly that identifier?  Is the segue connected from the view that is calling performSegueWithIdentifier?

Comment: Yes I create seque with this identifier and it's connected from view that calling perfomSequeWithIdentifier to second view

Comment: Is there a reason you are calling it inside of the viewDidLoad?  I'd try moving it to viewDidAppear maybe.

Comment: I move it to viewDidAppear and it works. Thanks a lot

Comment: Have you tried setting sender to "nil" instead of "self" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move it to viewDidAppear.  Won't perform segue until it shows up.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to know the reason it didn't work for you in viewDidLoad, you can look at my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10413993/761135)