# Certain View opens on first launch

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, nsuserdefaults

I want that if you launch the App for the first Time, a certain `UIView` opens. But if you `launch` it later this `UIView` shouldn't be able to see.

How can I program this ?

I use Storyboards and I've setter up my view already in Storyboard.

Here is what I've already coded:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];

    if ( ![[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] 
              boolForKey:@"hasPerformedFirstLaunch"]) {

        //View opens

        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES 
                                              forKey:@"hasPerformedFirstLaunch"];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

    } else {
        //RootView opens
    }    
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
```

So what can I enter at **//View** opens and **//RootView** opens?
Thank you really much!

Comment: possible duplicate of [iPhone: How do I detect when an app is launched for the first time?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/308832/iphone-how-do-i-detect-when-an-app-is-launched-for-the-first-time)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Perform Segue on ViewDidLoad](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8221787/perform-segue-on-viewdidload)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already prepared everything, you just have to show a specific `UIView` you want. Maybe you have it already created inside another class, then initialize it and add it to your main view, maybe like this.

```
MyUIViewExtension *viewExt = [MyUIViewExtension alloc] initWithFrame:....];
// add some other properties
[self.view addSubview:viewExt];
```

But it is up to you in which way a `UIView` will be shown.

---

To Add the `UIView` from the `UIStoryboard`, you have set an identifier. I would prefer to use the `UIViewController` name:

[image]

Inside your class, insert these lines of code:

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main_iPhone" 
                                                     bundle:nil];
NSString *strVC = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [ViewController class]];
ViewController *viewController = 
  [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:strVC];
```

Of course it would be better to create the ViewController as a Class variable so you can use it after creation.

Comment: how can I just show a view controller that I've already set up in Storyboard?

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you really aim to do. If you just want to add a view within the regular view of your current view controller, then you can add it as suggested or simply unhide it and hide it otherwise. 
You may hide it per default in Interface Builder (resp. Storyboard Editor) or hide it in the else branch.

OR you can present a view controller. You could so by programmatically segueing to a segue that is defined (and named with an id) in your storyboard or you can present it using your navigation controller - if you have one - or you can present it modally. A modal presentation works regardless if you have a navigation controller or not. A modal presentation does not need to cover the full screen, but it may well do.

So - it depends.

Do not expect some really reasonable piece of code - reasonable in the context of your question - until you reveal what you prefer or at least how it should look like.