# Segues are not performed

Tags: ios, swift

I'm developing a login view. I'm using Parse for the backend. The idea is very regular. If the user has registered already the app lets him in with no additional inconvenience. I put this code in `viewDidLoad()`:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()

        if PFUser.currentUser() != nil {

            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("login", sender: self)

        }
    }
```

After the app is compiled, it goes through that block of code but the login segue are not performing. Please let me know your suggestions what's wrong with? Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: Does the segue exist? Also, what kind of segue are you using? If it's a push segue then you'll need a UINavigationController.

Comment: Yes, it certainly exists. The type is `show`.

Comment: You can't perform a segue in `viewDidLoad()` because the view isn't visible yet. Move to `viewWillAppear()`. See [Perform Segue on ViewDidLoad](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8221787/perform-segue-on-viewdidload).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't possible to perform a segue in the `viewDidLoad` method.

Move it into the `viewDidAppear`method and it will work.