# UserDefaults not working on didload in my project

Tags: swift, nsuserdefaults

I have a login screen `LoginViewController` and homescreen `HomeScreenController` which is pushed when the user is successfully logged in).
I have declared a variable for UserDefaults as below in a seperate class:

```
class User {
    static var isLoggedIn = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey:"islogged")
}
```

When the  user clicks login Button, the code is as below

```
ButtonAction:
{
    User.isLoggedin = true
    //Performsegue........to homescreen
}

ViewDidload {

    if user.isloggedin == true {
        //Performsegue......homescreen
    }
    else {
        Show some alerts
    }
}
```

Here in my case...nothing happens...sorry for the rough code since I am using my smartphone to ask this question.

Am I missing something in appdelegate or somewhere else.
I just want to use the variables as it is because I don't want to change the entire code in my project.
The project is actually complicated and I just made an example to make you guys understand my situation.
This is not the exact code.

Answer (score 2):

Using a class with a static variable for a `UserDefaults` value is bad practice. Apart from that setting the static variable doesn't update the value in `UserDefaults`.

In the button action set the value in `UserDefaults` and perform the segue

```
@IBAction func login(_ sender : Any)  {
    UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey:"islogged")
    performSegue(...
}
```

In `viewDidLoad` get the value directly from `UserDefaults`

```
func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    if UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey:"islogged") {
        performSegue(...
    } else {
        // present error
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is happening coz you are calling the UserDefaults within the `User` class. This does not get executed until the class is initialized.

Try to do this directly in `viewDidLoad()`, it should work.

```
if UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey:"islogged") {
    Performsegue......homescreen
}else{
    Show some alerts
}
```

Comment: Yess but the point i was trying to make was that you should not use a UserDefault within a static variable class. It not good practice. You can also do what vadian has suggested. Thats the best approach.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead of  your isLoggedIn line of code

```
static var isLoggedIn: Bool {
    get {
        return UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "isLoggedIn")
    }
    set {
        UserDefaults.standard.setValue(newValue, forKey: "isLoggedIn")
        UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't use `setValue(` in `UserDefaults` unless you can explain why KVC is needed. And don't use `synchronize()`.

Comment: I've been storing project preferences this way for a while now. I'm not really sure about what you mean but I'm going to do some research. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're probably trying to achieve this:

```
class User {
    static var isLoggedIn: Bool {
        get {
            return UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "islogged")
        }
        set(aIsLoggedIn) {
            UserDefaults.standard.set(aIsLoggedIn, forKey: "islogged")
        }
    }
}
```

The problem with your code is that you don't save the state of `isLoggedIn`, so at every startup the value is always `false`

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have a problem with the call to `performSegue:`. You cannot call this method on `viewDidLoad` because the viewcontroller is not yet fully setup. Try moving your `viewDidLoad` to `viewDidAppear`

Move viewDidLoad code to viewDidAppear

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool){
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    if User.isLoggedIn{
        performSegue("someIdentifier")
    }else{
       //show some alerts. 
    }

}
```

Also, use a computed var for your `isLoggedIn`. 
taken from Marco:

```
  static var isLoggedIn: Bool {
        get {
            return UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "islogged")
        }
        set(aIsLoggedIn) {
            UserDefaults.standard.set(aIsLoggedIn, forKey: "islogged")
        }
    }
```

[Perform Segue on ViewDidLoad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8221787/perform-segue-on-viewdidload)

Comment: I roughly wrote those methods...i only want to mention userdefaults problem...even if i use print...it doesnt show success..so pls

Answer (score 0):

In your code

```
class User {    
    static var isLoggedIn = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey:"islogged")    
}
```

The 'isLoggedIn' is just a value type. It will not change by UserDefaults.standard's some value's changing. Because your declare is just set a default value to that.if you want to have a variable to imply the global unique semantic, you must insure that modify it in the same address, and get it from the same address too.

Comment: I have to store username and password also in userdefaults.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to hide login vc if user was logined, right?
Do it in HomeVC

```
@IBAction func login(_ sender : Any)  {
   if login == true{
      UserDefaults.standart.set("true", forKey:"islogged")
    }
}
```

And paste it to AppDelegate

```
var window: UIWindow?


func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    var initialViewController: UIViewController

    if UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "islogged") == "true"//your condition if user is already logged in or not
    {
        // if already logged in then redirect to MainViewController

        initialViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HomeVC") as! UITabBarController // 'MainController' is the storyboard id of HomeViewController
    }
    else
    {
        //If not logged in then show LoginViewController
        initialViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LoginVC") as! SignInViewController // 'LoginController' is the storyboard id of LoginViewController

    }

    self.window?.rootViewController = initialViewController

    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

    return true
}
```